# why jenkins job is not running at scheduled time midnight

Tags: jenkins, schedule

[settings for scheduled job in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucwzk.png)

my job is not running automatically as the settings in the screenshot shows that it should run at that time. please help on this

Answer (score -1):

You should choose "Build Periodically" option and give "0 0 * * *" to run the job on midnight everyday.

Refer 
    https://crontab.guru/every-night-at-midnight